# How can I access all objects of class data.frame inside .GlobalEnv in R

Tags: r

I have 8,000 `data.frame`s inside my global environment (`.GlobalEnv`) in R, for example

```
head(ls(.GlobalEnv))
#[1] "db1" "db2" "db3" "db4" "db5"
tail(ls(.GlobalEnv))
#[1] "db7996" "db7997" "db7998" "db7999" "db8000"
```

How can I access each of the `data.frame`s?

I could access the `data.frame`s using `.GlobalEnv$"db1"`, but it is useless because I want to carry out a linear regression for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another solution:

```
db1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3),y = c(1.1,1.2,1.3))
db2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4),y = c(2,2.1,2.2,2.3))
db3 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5),y = c(3,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4))
ls()
#[1] "db1" "db2" "db3"
nombres <- ls()
eval(parse(text = nombres[1]))
#  x   y
#1 1 1.1
#2 2 1.2
#3 3 1.3
lm(y~x,data = eval(parse(text = nombres[1])))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could use a combination of `eapply` and `mget` to put all `data.frame`s that are present in the global environment in a `list`:

```
x <- eapply(.GlobalEnv, 'is.data.frame')
dflist <- mget(names(x[unlist(x)]), .GlobalEnv)
```

Then you can use for example `lapply(dflist, ...)` to run a regression on each of them.

---

A very concise alternative approach contributed by @RichardScriven in the comments is:

```
dflist <- Filter(is.data.frame, as.list(.GlobalEnv))
```

Comment: nice, hadn't thought of `eapply`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach I can think of would be a basic `for` loop using `mget`.

```
for(df in ls(.GlobalEnv)){
    print(get(df))
}
```

You can then apply whatever operation you like on the `mget` result.

**Note** - this assumes the only variables in the environment are `data.frames` for your purposes as it doesn't discriminate  A more restrictive `for` loop would be:

```
for(df in ls(.GlobalEnv)){
    if(is.data.frame(get(df))){
        print(head(get(df)))
    }
}
```

which just uses `is.data.frame` to check if the object is indeed a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
.Globalenv[ls()]
```

Can also restrict to only items beginning with 'db' using regex patterns

Comment: I don't understand this.  You can't subset an  environment.  Once you fix the typo in `.GlobalEnv` it still gives an error.