# Add new column to data.frame through loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have n number of data.frame i would like to add column to all data.frame

```
a <- data.frame(1:4,5:8) 
b <- data.frame(1:4, 5:8)
test=ls()

for (j in test){
  j = cbind(get(j),IssueType=j)
}
```

Problem that i'm running into is

```
j = cbind(get(j),IssueType=j)
```

because it assigns all the data to `j` instead of `a`, `b`.

Comment: The standard way in R would be to keep all related data.frames in a `list` and use `lapply` to to loop over all of them and create new columns

Comment: can you help me with a sample code

Comment: Yes. What is the new column IssueType supposed to hold? simply `a` and `b` (the names of the data.frames)?

Comment: Yup, I am trying to put the data frame name as new column
> a
  X1.4 X5.8 Issu
1    1    5    a
2    2    6    a
3    3    7    a
4    4    8    a

something like thid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, it's mostly better to keep related data in a list structure. If you already have the data.frames in your global environment and you want to get them into a list, you can use:

```
dflist <- Filter(is.data.frame, as.list(.GlobalEnv))
```

This is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35372208/3521006) and makes sure that you only get `data.frame` objects from your global environment.

You will notice that you now already have a named list:

```
> dflist
# $a
#   X1.4 X5.8
# 1    1    5
# 2    2    6
# 3    3    7
# 4    4    8
# 
# $b
#   X1.4 X5.8
# 1    1    5
# 2    2    6
# 3    3    7
# 4    4    8
```

So you can easily select the data you want by typing for example

```
dflist[["a"]]
```

If you still want to create extra columns, you could do it like this:

```
dflist <- Map(function(df, x) {df$IssueType <- x; df}, dflist, names(dflist))
```

Now, each data.frame in `dflist` has a new column called `IssueType`:

```
> dflist
# $a
#   X1.4 X5.8 IssueType
# 1    1    5         a
# 2    2    6         a
# 3    3    7         a
# 4    4    8         a
# 
# $b
#   X1.4 X5.8 IssueType
# 1    1    5         b
# 2    2    6         b
# 3    3    7         b
# 4    4    8         b
```

In the future, you can create the data inside a list from the beginning, i.e.

```
dflist <- list(
  a = data.frame(1:4,5:8) 
  b = data.frame(1:4, 5:8)
)
```

Comment: > a
  X1.4 X5.8
1    1    5    
2    2    6    
3    3    7    
4    4    8    

I need to add new column which represent data.frame name 
 Sample output that i am looking for 

> a
  X1.4 X5.8 Issu
1    1    5    a
2    2    6    a
3    3    7    a
4    4    8    a

Comment: @PraveenRKaruppannan, that's what I demonstrated in my answer.. did you check it?

Comment: this does the job like charm, but now how to I split them up

Comment: @PraveenRKaruppannan, why would you want to? Just keep them sitting in a list. As I said, that would be the R way to do things. If you insist on putting them back separately in the global environment, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/17697397/3521006

Comment: I have to regroup them into single dataset  which need to be pushed into DB

Comment: @ docendo discimus,the link you did the job i was looking for .thanks a lot
I will add the complete code below I will help someone like me

Answer (score 0):

To create a list of your data.frames do this:

> a <- data.frame(1:4,5:8); b <- data.frame(1:4, 5:8); test <- list(a,b)

This allows you to us the lapply function to perform whatever you like to do with each of the dataframes, eg:

```
out <- lapply(test, function(x) cbind(j))
```

For most data.frame operations I recommend using the packages dplyr and tidyr.

Comment: > a
  X1.4 X5.8
1    1    5    
2    2    6    
3    3    7    
4    4    8    

I need to add new column which represent data.frame name 
 Sample output that i am looking for 

> a
  X1.4 X5.8 Issu
1    1    5    a
2    2    6    a
3    3    7    a
4    4    8    a

Answer (score 0):

wooo wooo

here is answer for the issue
helped by @docendo discimus

Created Dataframe

> a <- data.frame(1:4,5:8) 
>   b <- data.frame(1:4, 5:8)

Group data.frame into list

> dflist <- Filter(is.data.frame, as.list(.GlobalEnv))

Add's extra column

> dflist <- Map(function(df, x) {df$IssueType <- x; df}, dflist, names(dflist))

unstinting the data frame

> list2env(dflist ,.GlobalEnv)