# Load and rename shapefiles in loop R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to load a set of shapefiles into R using a loop. I am trying to find a way to name the loaded shapefile using the name as it stored in the vector used for the loop.

When I run the following code the loaded shapefile is named "s" instead of "spain", "france", or "portugal".

I have tried something like `paste(print(s))` but it is not successful.

## Make list of all names

`shapefiles<-c("spain","france","portugal")`

## Load files

`for (s in shapefiles) {`

`combine<-paste(s,"borders.shp",sep = "")`

`s<-st_read(paste("./repository/",print(combine), sep=""))`

`}`

SOLUTION:

## Make list of all names

`shapefiles<-c("spain","france","portugal")`

## Load files

`for (s in 1:length(shapefiles)) {`

`combine<-paste(shapefiles[s],"borders.shp",sep = "")`

`assign(shapefiles[s],st_read(paste("./repository/",print(combine), sep="")))  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and I solved it using the `assign()` function.

*E.g.*

```
# Get the names of the  shp
shapefiles<-c("spain","france","portugal")

# The assign() function!!!!    :D
for(i in 1:length(shapefiles)){
  
  assign(shapefiles[i], st_read(paste("./repository/shapefile.shp",print(combine), sep=""))) 
  
}
```

Something like that. Just I am not sure with the `st_read()` function but you can modify it for your problem.

Comment: Hi @FrsLry, thank you for answering this question. Your code is interesting but the "i" is numeric when I call `combine<-paste(i,"borders.shp",sep = "")` instead of being "spain" or "portugal". Do you have a fix?

Comment: If you want to use combine I would use: `combine<-paste(shapefiles[i],"borders.shp",sep = "")`. I guess that you want a filename like `franceborders.shp`

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix:

## All into a list

```
dflist<-Filter(is.data.frame, as.list(.GlobalEnv))
```

## Create a mapid column

```
dflist<-Map(function(df, x){df$mapeid<-gsub("(_\\d).*","\\1",x); df}, dflist, names(dflist))
```

From this discussion [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946822/add-new-column-to-data-frame-through-loop-in-r]