# How can I list only the data frame objects in R?

Tags: r, object, dataframe

Is there a way to list objects based on their classes ? For example, list only the dataframe objects in the workspace.

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371882/how-can-i-access-all-objects-of-class-data-frame-inside-globalenv-in-r)

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks for the link. I liked the `dflist <- Filter(is.data.frame, as.list(.GlobalEnv))` solution .

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way with `sapply` and `class` to retrieve the names of the objects in the environment that are data.frames:

```
ls()[sapply(ls(), function(i) class(get(i))) == "data.frame"]
```

Comment: Why are you complicating this? Use this `ls()[sapply(ls(),function(t) is.data.frame(get(t)))]`

Comment: That would return something different than what I said. That would be a logical vector. I am returning the names of the objects. I'm not sure that your statement is that much cleaner than mine.

Comment: The exact code is already there in the dupe post which was dupe tagged 4 mins before this was posted.

Comment: @user2100721 Sorry for the confusion. It was the other way around. Thanks for asking. To be clear, `ls()[sapply(ls(), function(i) class(get(i))) == "data.frame"]` didn't list the data table objects (which are dataframes too) but `ls()[sapply(ls(),function(t) is.data.frame(get(t)))]` listed all dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (obj in ls()) { 
    if(class(get(obj)) == "data.frame")
       print(obj)
}
```